# How to add a Custom Class on a String of PHP

Tags: php

```
<li><b><i class="fa fa-credit-card-alt" aria-hidden="true">
</i>Payments Accepted</b><br>
<?php
$geodir_payment_methods = $post->geodir_payment_methods;
                          $string = explode(",", $geodir_payment_methods);
                         foreach ($string as $str) {
  echo "<span class= ". $geodir_payment_methods .">" . $str . "</span>"; }?>
```

Using Geodirectory I'm trying to create a string for my inputs that each has its own separate class based on what it's named.

The problem I run into is when I look at it the `<class="American Express" Visa>`
when I only want the American express to show up.

Comment: Not sure your question makes much sense. Are you trying to hide / display something based on some rules?

Comment: Apologies, but your question is a bit unclear. Can you add some more explanation? What's not working that you would like to work, or what is working that you're not expecting?...

Comment: `if(string == x){...}`, in a nutshell or a ternary operator.

Comment: I highlighted the `<class="American Express" Visa>` in edit I made because you need to use ticks around those `\`` but it's unclear as to why there are 2 different kinds of credit card names there.

Answer (score 0):

You do realise that you're outputting all of the methods into the class?

```
foreach ($string as $str) {
  echo "<span class= ". $geodir_payment_methods .">" . $str . "</span>";
}
```

Surely should be:

```
foreach ($string as $str) {
  echo "<span class= ". $str .">" . $str . "</span>";
}
```

You might want to use `strtolower()` on the first `$str` too as you're putting it in a class.

Also seems like you're missing some quotes in the echo but hard to say without seeing exactly what data `$post->geodir_payment_methods` spits out.

Comment: Thank You Codeth, this solved my problem. Just so you know $post->geodir_payment_methods was  spitting out forms of payment like American Express, Discover, and others.

The reason I wanted to do this was that my client wanted them to be actual cards that spit out and one solution I found was adding a background image them. But since they where all in the same class I couldn't do it.

Anyway point is thank you for your help again and have a great day.